# Static ip addressed hardware unreachable

Tags: tcpip

I need help, I have multiple things (NAS box's and the like) on a static 10.10.10.x network.

My new situation forced me to use an Air Card on one laptop and using Internet connection sharing to allow the other computers access to the Internet. (everything is plugged into a single switch)

ICS, apparently, forces you to a specific IP address (192.168.137.1), now I can't access the static addressed hardware. I thought I saw someone use route.exe to do this, but I cant find enough information to do it.

if the ICS computer is 192.168.137.1 and 2 of the NAS boxes are 10.10.10.82 and 10.10.10.83 what do I need to type to make them accessible to the Windows 8.1 ICS computer?

`Static IP Hardware                         Static IP Hardware
.-----------------.                       .-----------------.
| NAS 10.10.10.82 |---------\   /---------| NAS 10.10.10.83 |
.-----------------.          | |          .-----------------.
                             | |
                          .--------.
                          | SWITCH |
                          .--------.
 DHCP Laptop                 | |            Windows 8.1 Pro
.--------------------.       / \          .------------------.
| LAP 192.168.37.100 |------/   \---------| LAP 192.168.37.1 | (ICS)
.--------------------.                    .------------------.
                                                 || Internet Connection`

I tried using route:

`route ADD 10.10.10.82 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1
route ADD 10.10.10.83 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1`

didn't work, and neither did:

`route ADD 10.10.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1`

They are all connected to the same switch, it's ridiculous that the machines cant see each other.

How can I make them accessible so I can change the Static addresses to the 192.168.37.x
(assume I have no access to the boxes cause their in the walls, and assume I don't know networking.)

Comment: Why not use a proper router rather than ICS? Why exactly are you using ICS?

Comment: ICS is a pain in a specific part of the body, why not use a (wireless) router for the internet connection? And to your question, if you can add a 10.10.10.something as a secondary ip to the windows 192.168.37.1 interface

Comment: All I have is a USB air card, can I plug that into a "proper router"?  WiFi is not an option, ever. There has to be a way to access the lost hardware with some setting. I don't know networking, I've always meant to learn it, just never found the time.

Comment: Is the DHCP laptop a Windows, OS X or other?  The OS makes a slight differenence for the syntax of the `route` command

Comment: All 30 Laptops are Microsoft Windows, however that should be irrelevant, I just want, from the ICS computer to access the lost hardware to get them onto the network as everything else.

Comment: The syntax for the route command is slightly different between Windows, OS X and Linux, I wanted to verify before giving an answer with syntax for the wrong OS

Comment: Does the switch have an IP address and if so what happens if you set that as the gateway?  If it is possible to access the machines on the `10.10.10.0` network and they can correctly see to the outside world could you try sending a trace route from one of those to see where the GW is?  Also make sure that you include the interface option so the traffic is routed through the correct interface on the ICS system with the `route add` command

Comment: The switch is just a little box from Best Buy, theres no admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in the question it seems like the gateway to the internet for the ICS is not the switch in the middle of everything on your diagram.  If this is the case then the `if` or interface option needs to be included with the route command to make sure traffic is routed through the right interface.

On Windows(I think this is correct I do not use Windows systems that often)

```
route add 10.10.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.1 if <name of ethernet interface>
```

Will add the interface to the `route add` command.  According to this [Windows Doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc757323(v=WS.10).aspx) if no interface option is specified the interface is determined from the gateway IP.  If the gateway IP is not the same as the switch IP it will be trying to route your traffic through the wrong interface.

To view the IP routing tables you can run

```
route print
```

Which will show the routes, from there you should be able to see if the new route was added correctly.  If the route was not added to the routing tables after the `route add` issuance there is possibly some deeper issue.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/619786/use-commandline-to-show-disabled-network-interfaces-in-windows-mobile-broadban)

```
wmic nic get NetConnectionID
```

Will show the names o the network interfaces, which should give you enough info to add the route.

Comment: I did type route /?, I tried the IF like they said, didn't work.  But do you know this to be the way to see them.  the whole route.exe might be a red herring as far as I know.

Comment: There is only 2 interfaces, the Ethernet card, and the USB Air Card.  The RJ45 has the 192.168.137.1, the air card has a public IP.

Comment: It is possible, I normally use Linux and OS X, and `route` is how I would deal with this issue on those systems.  If you can print out the routing tables on the ICS system, laptop and/or NAS boxes it might help to work out exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Thats good to hear. This is frustrating, there's no reason why Windows shouldn't be able to see the other networks (in a logical world, not a network engineer's)

Comment: I can't do anything with the NAS boxes but look at them in the physical world.  They are invisible. I can post the route table later for the ICS computer, the DHCP computer doesn't need to see anything, I need a temporary kludge to change the IPs, I am presently away from the network.

Comment: What device in this diagram is managing the network for the NAS boxes?  Is there a DHCP server that assigns them their IP addresses?  If the switch is completely unmanaged it seems like there must be some other connected networking device managing the 10,10.10.0/24 network.  Without setting up the routing tables it will not matter if the devices are connected to the same switch because hosts on the 192.168.37.1/24 network will only be able to communicate with other hosts onto that network, and if it is configured out to the rest of the internet through the gateway.

Comment: No, I had every network item (NAS/Computer/DVR) with their own Static IP's.  Never had any issue till the Internet access changed.  Now with ICS I was forced to use DHCP from the ICS machine, which is ok, but I need to get access to the static ip hardware that is now inaccessible.